# Finding a sublist within a list in Python

Tags: python, list, sublist

I thought this would be fairly easy to find but no luck.   Basically if I have two lists, I want to test that one list is the subset of another:

```
list1 = ['car', 'cart', 'dog']
list2 = ['car',  'dog']
```

`list1 == list 2` should be `True` because `list2` is a subset of `list1`.  My solution is way too complex.  My question is - is there a simple function to do this with lists?  More importantly, to test for subsets, is list even the right way to go or is there a better data structure I should study to solve this.  Trying to implement my own version of an apriori algorithm. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: @NickA I think the OP is aware, they are just using this to explain how their function *should* work so a similar method to `==` but one that checks for subsets

Comment: @Joe hmm, I suppose that would indeed make sense

Comment: @PatrickArtner my code is long and far from efficient.  I simply asked about the presence of a better data structure to do this and have only been working in Python for a few months.  I just didn’t learn about sets yet.  You were once new and someone helped you too.

Comment: Hi Vaslo, welcome to stack overflow.  1.  show your attempt, even the code is bad/inefficient/completely broken, your questions will be better received for having shown an attempt before asking for solution  2.  "sublist" is ambiguous so you need to clarify some behavior - is the ordering important?  how should duplicates be handled? do you want a strict sublist, or is equality ok?

Comment: Hi Vasio, you should show your code so we (the community) ´:  see what lvl of skill you have, where your problems are, what kind of advice can be given and to demonstrate that you are not simply offloading your homework to SO. It is kindof a pre-requisit for your question to be "on-topic" and "worthy" of effort of the community. Reason behind it: Your question may be found 4 years later by some other gal searching SO - posed as is it is less worth for "seeing where your exact problem was" then with the code you should have added in the first place. Peace.

Comment: I both upvoted and close voted this question for a lack of [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Convert `list2` to a `set` and use the `issubset` method:

```
In [48]: list1 = ['car', 'cart', 'dog']

In [49]: list2 = ['car', 'dog']

In [50]: set(list2).issubset(list1)
Out[50]: True
```

Comment: well your answer works well, so +1 from me!

Comment: It’s ridiculous, someone helped me reduce code by dozens of lines using a structure I just don’t know about as a newb, and then question gets crushed.

Comment: @Vaslo Well, don't get discouraged by that.

Comment: @Vaslo, you've said *My solution is way too complex*, then not shown your solution that alone is reason enough for some people to downvote

Comment: It’s garbage and I’m embarrassed to show it.

Comment: Well it's the first time @Vaslo ever asked a question. God forbid it wasn't perfect

Comment: @NickA Would it kill that person to ask for it once?

Comment: @hee probably not but not much can be done about it except live and learn

Comment: @heemayl regardless of the other stuff, I thank you - this was very simple and I didn't think of casting the list to another structure. Didn't even know you could do that.

Comment: @Vaslo Glad i could help and welcome to SO :)

Comment: @Vaslo Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

You want a [multiset](https://github.com/wheerd/multiset).

```
>>> from multiset import Multiset  # pip install multiset
>>> Multiset(['car', 'dog']) <= Multiset(['car', 'cart', 'dog'])
True
>>> Multiset(['car', 'dog', 'dog']) <= Multiset(['car', 'cart', 'dog'])
False
```

`collections.Counter` is the standard library multiset, but [until v3.10](https://bugs.python.org/issue40755) it lacked the subset operator `<=`, so if you want to stick to standard library on Python < 3.10 then you will have to write the loop yourself rather than use set operations.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter1 = Counter(['car', 'dog'])
>>> counter2 = Counter(['car', 'cart', 'dog'])
>>> all(counter1[k] <= counter2[k] for k in counter1)
True
```

Comment: I just noticed this myself, but [3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) added support for subset comparison operators!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, nice! I always wondered why they were missing. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

Using list suggests not only that you are interested in the presence of the members but also their order. If order isn't important you should go for a set instead.

On the other hand you have to consider that you cannot have copies of the same member in a set which you can have in lists. Perhaps your after a third kind of data structure.

The biggest uncertainties for me with the question comes down to if the 'is subset' question takes order into account and possibly how duplicate entries are to be handled.

Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function that returns `True` if all elements in the iterable passed into it are `True`. So in our case, we can use a `generator-comprehension` which yields boolean values for whether each value in `list2` is in `list1`:

```
>>> all(i in list1 for i in list2)
True
```

Comment: This is quadratic, better to do this in linear time.

Comment: @wim Good point, I wasn't considering efficiency but should have been.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution assumes your input lists contain unique elements.

It won't work, for example, with `list1 = ['a', 'b']` and `list2 = ['a', 'a']`.

```
list1 = ['car', 'cart', 'dog']
list2 = ['car',  'dog']

set(list2) <= set(list1)  # True
```

If you want to check if it is a *proper subset*, in other words the two lists cannot be identical, you can use this:

```
set(list2) < set(list1)   # True
```